# I have integrated SUMO with 5G LENA. When we change the vehicle numbers in sumo it does not change the output in 5G LENA. Why is that?

Tags: sumo

At first we generated trace files from osm web wizard, by changing the vehicle number, picking the same area in the map. When we run that files in 5G LENA, it changes the output according to the vehicle number. But now we have created our own network in sumo. We used one cross junction in this simulation, a really simple network. with two roads having 2 lanes. And we have changed the vehicle number so many times. But the output in 5G LENA is always the same. I need the solution for this. We are doing this project for our final year project.

I tried changing vehicle number, vehicle type, acceleration, deceleration, different routes, increased number of vehicles(in the route file), then generated the trace files and run in 5G LENA (cttc-nr-v2x-demo-simple.cc file). But nothing worked.

Comment: Did you recheck visually with sumo-gui that the vehicle numbers changed? Have you generated further outputs you could have a look at?